# Is there any way to save Kivy Camera photo as base64 without exporting it to png?

Tags: python, ios, kivy, gallery

I would like to know if it is possible to save camera capture from kivy as base64 without exporting it to png and storing it on my device.
I'm using this code:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__camera__main__py.html
to take photo and save it as png.

Can I somehow avoid saving it as png outside and turn it into string or value or anything?

The reason why I'm asking for that is I want to send it as an attachment, and after exporting it to png, photo doesn't save itself on my Iphone. What comes with that my program can't later change it to base64 and send it because photo doesn't appear in my phone and that crashes my app.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Kacper, have you solved this? Want to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `export_as_image` to get a Kivy Image object, whose pixels you can manipulate as you like.

You may also find it interesting to look at [the source code for this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L725).

Comment: Ok but is there any way to change kivy.core.image.Image object into base64? I think I should .read() that but it doesn't have that attribute

Comment: I think you want something like `the_image.texture.pixels` (or more generally, you want to get the texture object, and you want to access its pixels attribute). I'm not sure what this returns, probably either a bytestring or a list of numbers, but either way you can reencode it however you like.